# Create 2d games with pyglet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d, pyglet

Is It Possible to create 2d games with [**Pyglet**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyglet/1.2.4) module? It is Used to create 3d games.
To Create 2d games we Use [**pygme**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygame).
Like creating a  simple *snake* game with pyglet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it absolutely can.  Pyglet is a great library but I wouldn't recommend it for beginners because it lacks community support. Most python game libraries seem to be in this boat.

Personally, I'm using a combination of Pygame and PyOpenGL for writing 2D and 3D games since there's good documentation and community support for both.  I use pygame for opening a window and receiving events from keyboard/mouse and OpenGL for all the rendering.

OpenGL is tough and its not something you should wander into lightly but there are lots of tutorials out there and that makes all the difference in the world.